# Utilizing jekyll framework with javascript kit password encryption

Tags: javascript, jekyll

Please bear with me, im new to the world of coding/dev.

Im trying to password protect a portion of my website that utilizes the jekyll framework.

Link to encryptor: http://www.javascriptkit.com/epassword/index.htm

I did as told and created 2 files: my site structure is as follows.

_posts

---

```
       _posts/2016-03-08-seq.markdown

       _posts/2016-03-08-yoga.markdown
```

---

seq.markdown is the page where I am running the script 
yoga.markdown is the page which I am trying to password protect

For some reason when I enter my password 'yoga' I get a page not found error. The path seems to have added /seq but I cannot figure out why.

```
Not Found

`/work/seq/yoga.html' not found.
```

I feel as if I am missing something very simple but cannot figure out what. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In your site's `_site` directory, can you find `/work/seq/yoga.html`? Is this the correct path? These are posts which often include the date somewhere in the URL, but you haven't specified that here.

Answer (score 0):

Your site sounds like it is generating pages of the form

```
_site/work/seq/index.html
_site/work/yoga/index.html
```

You will need to change the `permalink` property in your `_config.yml` and remove the trailing `/`

```
permalink: /work/:title
```

That should work.

Comment: never thought to check my _config.yml page. total miss. thanks so much!